# New sqlite3 database is locked

Tags: sqlite, filesystems, vagrant, nfs

I'm finding that new sqlite3 database files are locked before any use that I am aware of.

```
sqlite3 new.sqlite
sqlite> SELECT * FROM SQLITE_MASTER;
Error: database is locked
```

`lsof` on the new file is empty. Copying the database file to a new location doesn't help. Permissions on the file are OK.

How else can I determine why a new sqlite3 file might be locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, my best guess is that this is occuring because the database file is on an NFS mount for Vagrant. According to the docs:

> One should note that POSIX advisory locking is known to be buggy or
>   even unimplemented on many NFS implementations ... Your best defense
>   is to not use SQLite for files on a network filesystem.

https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

**I was able to resolve the issue by setting file permissions on the mounted folder on the host machine.**

Comment: Can you elaborate? What were the file permissions before and what did you change them to?

Comment: @jberryman I think I actually chowned it to my user on the host machine.