# SQLite3 Database File Locked to Reads and Integrity Checks

Tags: sqlite, panfs

A process crashed while trying to commit an insert of 2-3 million rows.  Now, I'm finding the database file is locked for all activity, including reading, dumping, and running an integrity check.

1. Can I unlock this database in some way or get sqlite3 to recover the file?
2. Is there any way of recovering the contents of this database file?  I *do* have a backup from 24 hours ago, but a variety of other data will be lost if I have to do a complete rollback to an older version of the database.

Code below:

```
$ sqlite3 dbFile.sqlite
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-08 14:26:16
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> PRAGMA integrity_check;
Error: database is locked
sqlite> .tables
Error: database is locked
sqlite> SELECT * FROM dbTable LIMIT 1;
Error: database is locked
```

Running `fuser` on the database file indicates that no processes are currently attempting to access the file.  There *is* a hot file in the same directory (i.e. `dbFile.sqlite-journal` exists).

Using stat, I see that the folder in question is of type `panfs`, which seems likely to be the cause of the issue. What can I do here?

Notably not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database), as the database is (1) not locked by any running process, as mentioned above, (2) locked for reading as well, and (3) due to the full read/write lock the `.dump` solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740613/4146714) is inapplicable (as `.dump` fails).

Closest related question is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673701/new-sqlite3-database-is-locked), although that one is on a different NFS filesystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unlock a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not! I've updated my question to clarify the key differences.

Comment: You mentioned NFS and panfs. Is this database on a network mount? That's known to have issues with locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the PanFS server(s) did not notice the crash, and so still report the write lock.

You could try to unmount and re-mount the file system on this machine, if possible.

Alternatively, copy both files (database *and* journal) elsewhere. When you open that database, SQLite will roll back the partial transaction.

Comment: I moved the database file to an ext2/ext3 FS and was able to open/dump the DB. Thanks!